# Azure Web App suddenly returns 401.72 for all request

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem which is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063048/azures-inbuild-website-authorization-throws-permission-error-after-returning-to#), but not quite.

We have a solution with two Azure Web Apps, built and deployed by Visual Studio Online. It has been working just fine for a few months, but suddenly all requests end in a 401.72 response:

> HTTP Error 401.71 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page.
>
> Most likely causes: The authenticated user does not have access to a
>   resource needed to process the request.
>
> Things you can try: Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for
>   this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing
>   rule for failed requests, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       EasyAuthModule_32bit
>   Notification     AuthenticateRequest Handler
>   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code    0x80004005
>   Requested URL    https://[appname]:80/ Physical Path
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot Logon Method    Not yet determined Logon User
>   Not yet determined
>
> More Information: This is the generic Access Denied error returned by
>   IIS. Typically, there is a substatus code associated with this error
>   that describes why the server denied the request. Check the IIS Log
>   file to determine whether a substatus code is associated with this
>   failure. View more information »
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

As far as I can figure out, no relevant configuration changes has been done.

Restarting the Web App and redeploying the solution didn't solve the problem

As it happens, we were due to recreate the environment anyway, and after this was done, the same deployment setup (with updated target) deployed successfully and it's working fine on the new Web App intsance.

Even if we now have a working environment, we'd really like to know what happened, so we can be sure it doesn't happen again.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had easy auth turned on. Do you expect it to be turned on? That appears to be causing the issue.

If you don't intend for it to be on, please turn it off via either portal ([old](https://manage.windowsazure.com)|[new](https://portal.azure.com)) by navigating to your Web App and finding it in your settings.

If you do intend for it to be on, you need to check your configuration to make sure you've properly set up AAD. Maybe the App Configuration within AAD has changed?

If neither of those things helps, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure where "Easy Auth" is enabled/disabled. All I can find in the portals, are "Authentication / Authorization" in both. This is enabled in the new portal (as it should) but in the old it says "You have not configured Azure Authentication / Authorization.". Not sure why, as I thought this was the same setting.

Comment: The settings in the AD application hasn't changed since the app was created, as far as I can see. The only thing I can imagine (and that I don't know for sure if is unchanged), is that the manifest has been changed. Is there a setting for this in the manifest?

Comment: After looking at the portals and reading your relpy again, I connected the dots :) It seems the auth. shouldn't have been enabled in our setup after all. Don't know how it got enabled, but when disabled things work again. Thank you!

Comment: Just a final note: This problem occured last week, but I see from the event log in the portal that the last time the config had changed, was three weeks ago, so still a bit puzzled regarding what happened...

Comment: I'm not sure whether who made the changes would be captured in your management logs. It's probably best to remind the team not to fiddle with knobs. I work for the team, and ironically the same thing happened, though more intentionally. For an internal site, someone turned on EasyAuth because it locks it down to folks on your AAD. Well I already had a login configured for the AAD application, so it just redirected over and over. Fun to debug. :)

Comment: If I migrated over from a mobile app, should I turn the easy authentication on? The authentication/authorization settings in my mobile app? Facebook was working for me since it was a mobileservice, but when I tried to set up google I turned on the easy auth. FB still works, but getting 401 errors when passing the google token in mobileservice.login

Comment: Did you mean from Mobile Services? You should not use the Authentication / Authorization feature until you are ready to do an "upgrade," which is a separate action from clicking the migration button. Migration: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/. Upgrade: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services/